# Obtaining a bimodal distribution from a beta distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution

I would like to create a bimodal distribution using the beta distribution.

Can someone explain how to obtain such a distribution?

I tried merging two different sample from a beta distribution, but I'm sure there's a more appropriate way.

```
a<-c(rbeta((50),10,1,1), rbeta((50),1,10,1))
```

Comment: Not sure why you think there's a better way. Other than normalizing your distribution,  your code is fine.  I suppose you could manually writing out a "two-beta distribution function and running `sample` on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beta distribution *is* bimodal for appropriate values of its parameters, e.g. (0.5,0.5):

```
set.seed(1)
hist(rbeta(10000,.5,.5))
```

[image: beta]